# How do I include bootstrap js in a marko app using lasso?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, marko, lasso.js

I'd like to include the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) JS in my [Marko](https://markojs.com/) app using [Lasso](https://github.com/lasso-js/lasso). How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install the required packages with `npm`:

```
npm install --save bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

Then, create a `browser.json` file in the same directory as the component that has the `<lasso-page />` tag. Add the appropriate paths under `dependencies`. With my component in `project-base/views/components/Layout/`, my `browser.json` looks like

```
{
  "dependencies": [
    "popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Finally, reference `browser.json` from your `<lasso-page />` tag:

```
<lasso-page package-path="./browser.json" />
```

Comment: @patrick-steele-idem noted in an edit that the paths in the `dependencies` array do not need to be relative; I'm updating this answer to reflect that.